# Accessing Android Content Provider inside Webview

Tags: html, android-webview, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

In Android. How do you access Content Provider inside your webview. It is showing content uri as not defined

```
google.visualization.Query(CONTENT_URI, opt_options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the chromium does not support content provider access of local files in android system. So the method is not possible.

Comment: Documentation on this: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview